# change_presence() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a problem in python, i'm coding my own discord.py bot and i have really annoying problem.

My code:

```
    import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import random


client = discord.Client()


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

print ("Discord version: " + discord.__version__)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
print ("Logged in as " + bot.user.name)
await client.change_presence(discord.Game(name="use !commands"))
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the positional argument you have in `change_presence` to a keyword argument: according to [the docs](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=change%20presence#discord.Client.change_presence), that would be `game`.

Hence

```
client.change_presence(discord.Game(name="use !commands"))
```

to

```
client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="use !commands")).
```

---

In addition if we check out the source code for `discord.py`, we can see the exact reason for your error.

[Line 409 in this file](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/gateway.py#L409) defines `change_presence` as

```
def change_presence(self, *, game=None, status=None, afk=False, since=0.0, idle=None)
```

we can see the asterisk (`*`) right after the `self` argument which is Python 3 semantics for accepting only keyword arguments after the asterisk.

You can see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/5695018) for some more information.

That means that all arguments after `self` are purely keyword arguments (need an identifier), you are passing an argument which coupled with `self` (passed in automatically) makes two positional arguments when the maximum positional arguments are just one (which is `self`). So you must change your positional argument to a keyword one.

Comment: Right now, my .py file won't start

Comment: Which version of `discord.py` are you using?

Comment: Latest discord.py, Python 3, Should i import from discord client?

Comment: The change I proposed should not cause any errors. Make sure the error is in this line and that you did not change anything else in the code. Also recheck your indentation as it is incorrect in the question.